# Atomic: if statement is entered even though the conditional is false

Tags: c++, debugging, atomic, visual-studio-debugging

**Edit: minimal reproducible example**

```
#include <atomic>
int main()
{
    std::atomic_uint atomic_write_position{ 0 };
    unsigned write_position = atomic_write_position.fetch_add(1);
    bool b = false;
    b = atomic_write_position.compare_exchange_weak(write_position, 0);
    if (b);
    {
        auto x = 0;
    }
}
```

In this example, `compare_exchange_weak` should fail because `atomic_write_position=1`, `write_position=0`, and does behave correctly returning false and over writing `write_position` with the value of `atomic_write_position`. However the if statement after does not behave correctly, and is entered even though b is false.

I'm using visual studio 16.9.2

Comment: Are you inspecting the value of `b` in the debugger and it's being shown as `false` when entering the if statement? Are you running a debug build or release?

Comment: Yes b is false when entering the statement. I'm running a debug build.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: With atomics, I'd be looking at registers and assembly stepping to be sure of the timing.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon `;` in the if-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the semi-colon ; in the if-statement

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says 'if b is false' but your test is for true.

```
if (b) //b is false
```

change it to:

```
if (!b) //b is false
```

Comment: negating b gives the same behavior